# Are there descendants of std::vector who can merge and sort?

Tags: c++, sorting, merge, stl, stdvector

I'm working with std::vectors for a graphical program. Those vectors contain positions on the screen, and they are sorted. Now I'd like to merge them together and keep the actual sorting, while removing possible duplicates, something like this:

```
vector1 : [2, 6, 10]
vector2 : [1, 5, 6, 10]
result  : [1, 2, 5, 6, 10]
```

For a good understanding: I have already programmed myself the function to do the actual merging, based on basic std::vector functions, like `at()`, `insert()`, `size()`, but my function seems to be a performance gap (O(n<sup>2</sup>), I believe).

I'm looking for other std classes (std::vector descendants if possible, for the ease of programming), who contain `merge()` and `sort(kind="unique")` as basic methods.

Does anybody know if such classes exist in STL?

Comment: Wrong mindset. STL algorithms are non-member function templates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

STL has this concept of **separation of containers and algorithms**, so while `std::vector` indeed does not have members to sort or merge it, STL provides all the required algorithms via non-member function templates that handle iterators.

E.g. to sort a vector you would call

```
std::sort(vector1.begin(),vector1.end());
```

Check [algorithm](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) header for further reference, namely `std::sort` and `std::merge`.

To merge and remove duplicates you can use `std::set_union`, which is probably your best bet. [Here is working code example](http://ideone.com/7Fk1Vu).

[Here](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/stl/iterators.html) is a tutorial on iterators, though for this specific task you would only need self-explanatory `vector::begin()` and `vector::end()`.

For removing duplicates from a single container you would usually use `std::unique()` or `std::unique_copy()`, as @unwind mentioned.

There is one caveat with `std::unique()` and other "removing" algorithms like `std::remove()`, which stems from that "separation of containers and algorithms" that I mentioned:
an algorithm has no means to actually **remove** elements from the container - it's been given an iterator or a range, but it has no idea about the actual type and implementation of the container.

So instead common approach is to just move the elements intended for removal to the end of the range, and then return the iterator to the first of these elements. Then you can call another function to do actual removal (notice how this time **it will be a container method**).

This is how it's done with `std::unique()`:

```
vec.erase(std::unique(vec.begin(), vec.end()), vec.end());
```

`std::unique_copy` will not require this trick, but it will pretty much copy the whole vector, so it makes sense only if you intended to copy it anyway.

Comment: Should probably say something about the requirement to remove dupes, too. `std::unique()`?

Comment: oh right, missed that part. Funny how this actually compicates things

Comment: What I really should've mentioned from the beginning is `std::set_union`. It's easy to overlook it - the name is a bit misleading I guess. It is the default solution for unique merging though.

Comment: Hello, @Ap31, `set_union()` is indeed what I am looking for, I've found it on the cplusplus.com reference, I've tested it and it's working fine. Maybe the best is to edit your first answer, like the final solution will be in the answer, instead of the following comments.

Comment: @Dominique I did edit the answer to add a mention of `set_union()`, do you want me to remove the whole `std::unique` part? I still consider it somewhat  relevant

Comment: No, there might be some relevant things there maybe for other people. Meanwhile I've accepted your answer.

Comment: I'd like to add the URL to this post which explains how to do the actual `set_union()`, it's "http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/set_union/", it is very important because the `resize()` function example shows how to handle duplicates.

Comment: @Dominique the `resize()` example is actually somewhat weird. Note that `resize()` is only used to throw away extra elements from the initial vector, and **NOT** for handling duplicates. Duplicates are already discarded by `set_union`. Reserving the vector to some specific size is sort of a bad strategy, I suggest using back_inserter instead. I'll add some expample code in a minute.

Comment: @Dominique I've added some ideone code (http://ideone.com/7Fk1Vu). `std::back_inserter` is an iterator that allows appending elements to the end of the vector, you can pass it to any algorithm that expects some destination, e.g. `std::copy`, `std::set_union` etc. The last `std::copy` call is only there for output.

Comment: Meanwhile I've managed to get the code working (not with `std::back_inserter()`, that goes wrong), but the resulting code is taking quite a long time, and I suppose this is due to the fact that both vectors are merged into a new one. Is there any function which merges two vectors by adding elements to one of the already existing vectors?

Comment: @Dominique how is `std::back_inserter` going wrong, I even provided a working sample on ideone:D adding elements to the existing vector is a slowest possible way, as it will require inserting elements in arbitrary positions, which is not a good task for `std::vector`. Can you share your code? You can make a new question out of it as this comment section is a bit overgrown